# Read the flutter firestore document and collation

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We have successfully read the flutter Firestore Documentation data into the Listview.Builder
The code is as follows

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

class championship extends StatefulWidget {
  const championship({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<championship> createState() => _championshipState();
}

class _championshipState extends State<championship> {

  ///Documents Ids
  List<String> docIDs = [];

  int a = 0;

  ///Get docIDs
  Future getDocId() async {
    if(a==0){
      a++;
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('championship').get().then(
            (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach(
                (document) {
              // print(document.reference);
              docIDs.add(document.reference.id);
            }
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    if(a == 1){
      getDocId();
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('championship',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 17),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 30,),
            const SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: getDocId(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: docIDs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index){
                        return ListTile(
                          title: ElevatedButton(
                            child: Text(docIDs[index],
                              style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                            onPressed: (){
                                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context){
                                      return competition_main_page(
                                      );
                                    }
                                  ),
                                );
                            },
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black38)
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[above code execution screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwV4W.png)

What I want is to show 20231001 data when I press 20231001 and 20231008 data when I press 20231008
No matter how hard I look, I can't find it Please help me

[Here's the fire store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPe2l.png)

return competition_main_page(place:snapshot.data[index].data['place']);
Then, receive String place; from composition_main_page and required this.I tried to place, etc., but failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change From:
snapshot.data[index].data['place']

Change To:
snapshot.data[index].data()['place']

You also need to pass the DocumentSnapshot to competition_main_page().